# Copy a single word from an sms text message

Tags: 8.0, sms

What gestures would I need to use in order to copy a single word from an sms text message onto the clipboard?

So far I have figured out that it is possible to copy the entire message by holding my finger down on the message for a short time, at which point a menu appears with a copy option, this copies the entire message to the clipboard. I then paste the message into word and then copy the single word that I want onto the clipboard.

I've found that this is a bit long winded and would like to copy a single word directly from the text message. How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can “[longtouch](http://google.about.com/od/l/g/long_touch_click_android.htm)” on the message—as you are now doing—but then select <kbd>forward</kbd>.

This will give you an editable version of the message.

You can then tap the word(s) you want, copy, and back out.

Answer (score 1):

While you are bound by having to copy the contents of the entire text message, you can save yourself one step by tapping the word (or group of words) you want to copy and pasting the copied content on to the text message thread itself (instead of doing it in Word).

Don't worry about that text left over in the thread...just hit the back button and it will be removed from memory.

Comment: I've found that the text hangs around when I do that, but it definitely makes things easier than going to word to get the word, thanks!

Comment: Oh I see. I am using Windows Phone 7.8 so that might explain why we see the different behaviour

Answer (score 0):

As you have found, it is not possible to copy a single word from the default messaging app.The best you can do is copy the entire message, paste it, and then select all the text you want to remove and delete it.